# Validation IRAN Code Meli in Ajax ActiveForm Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, active-form

how to Validation IRAN Code Meli in Ajax ActiveForm Yii2

Correct:

```
2595722751
```

not Correct:

```
2595722752
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1: in view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```

Step2: function in model

```
public function checkCodeMeli()
    {
        $code_melli = $this->code_meli;

        if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/', $code_melli)) {
            $this->addError('code_meli', 'کد ملی باید 10 رقم باشد');
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            if (preg_match('/^' . $i . '{10}$/', $code_melli)) {
                $this->addError('code_meli', 'کد ملی صحیح وارد نشده است');
            }
        }

        for ($i = 0, $sum = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
            $sum += ((10 - $i) * intval(substr($code_melli, $i, 1)));
        }

        $ret = $sum % 11;
        $parity = intval(substr($code_melli, 9, 1));
        if (($ret < 2 && $ret == $parity) || ($ret >= 2 && $ret == 11 - $parity)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $this->addError('code_meli', 'کد ملی صحیح وارد نشده است');
        }
    }
```

Step3: rule in Model

```
['code_meli', 'checkCodeMeli'],
```

Step4: in controller

```
$model = new Model();

if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
   Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
   return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```